# This page isn’t working right now. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following error message when I fill the form:

> This page isn’t working right now. If the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 405.

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .forms import CommentForm
from django.views import View

class UltimatePostView(View):

 def get(self, request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug )
    context = {
        "post": post,
        "post_tags" : post.tag.all(),
        "comment_form" : CommentForm()
    }
    return render(request, "gold-blog/post-detail.html", context )
    
def post(self, request, slug):
    comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug )

    if comment_form.is_valid():
      comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
      comment.post = post
      comment.save()

      return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("post-detail-page", args=[slug]))

    context = {
        "post": post,
        "post_tags" : post.tag.all(),
        "comment_form" : comment_form
    }

    return render(request, "gold-blog/post-detail.html", context)
```

Comment: I suggest you contact the site owner

Comment: Http 405 - method not allowed, which method you use in form?

Comment: Please show the relevant template, post-detail.html.

Comment: Here is the post-detail template: ``` {% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}
{{post.title}}
{% endblock %}

<div>
<form action = "{% url "post-detail-page" post.slug %}" width="100" height="120" method = "POST">
     {% csrf_token %}
  {% for form_field in comment_form %}
  <div class ="form-control">
    {{ form_field.label_tag }}
    {{ form_field }}
    {{ form_field.errors }}
  
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
   <button> Save Comment </button> 
</form>

</div>

{% endblock %}```

Comment: forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Comment
      exclude = ["posts"]
      labels = {
          "name": "Name",
          "email": "Email",
          "text": " Comment"
      } 
```

Comment: I found errors in the post-detail.html template: I omitted spaces in {{ post-title }} and also wrote an extra </div> just before {% endblock %}. The page works now.